# Support vector machine plotting

Tags: r

I was trying to plot a SVM classification. However I encountered a problem that I have no idea how to fix. I looked at documentation and some videos but still stuck. Here is my code

```
library(ISLR)
svm.oj2 <- svm(Purchase~.,data=OJ,kernel='linear',cost=1,scale = F)
plot(svm.oj2,data=OJ)
```

Here is the error:

```
 Error in plot.svm(svm.oj2, data = OJ) : missing formula.
```

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
library(ISLR)
library(e1071)
svm.oj2 <- svm(Purchase~.,data=OJ,kernel='linear',cost=1,scale = F)

plot(OJ, col = 1:1000 %in% svm.oj2$index + 1)
```